# Method call: Collections.emptyList() shows different behaviour in different cases?

Tags: java, list, exception, collections

As per comment of `Collections.emptyList()` method
it returns an empty immutable list.

It is justified if we do direct assignment to the object. 
Example:

```
public class ImmutableList {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String> namesList=Collections.emptyList();
        String[] names = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};
        namesList.addAll(Arrays.asList(names));     
    }

    private List<String> getList() {
        String[] names = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};
        return Arrays.asList(names);
    }
}
```

If we run the above program, it throws following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
    at org.learn.list.ImmutableList.main(ImmutableList.java:11)
```

However, if we assign the output of a method to this variable, then it runs fine. 
Example:

```
public class ImmutableListTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String> namesList=Collections.emptyList();
        ImmutableListTest2 ce = new ImmutableListTest2();       
        namesList = ce.getList(); 
        namesList.forEach(System.out::print);
    }

    private List<String> getList() {
        String[] names = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};
        return Arrays.asList(names);
    }
}
```

Ouput:

```
Name1Name2Name3
```

My question is namesList should be immutable in any case. 
Why we are able to mutate this variable in second case.

It should throw `UnsupportedOperationException` in all cases. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Because you didn't add anything to the empty list in the second example :)

Comment: Got it! object is just replaced by another object in second case. However, in first case we just tried to modify the object, that's why the exception. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`namesList` is not immutable. The original `List<String>` that it referenced (returned by `Collections.emptyList()`) is immutable.

`namesList` is a variable of `List<String>` type. Hence you can assign to it a reference to any `List<String>` instance, mutable or not. When you assign to it the `List` returned by `ce.getList()`, it no longer references an immutable `List`.

If you want to prevent that, make it a `final` variable, which will prevent it from being re-assigned:

```
final List<String> namesList=Collections.emptyList();
```

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik nope, it returns a fixed sized list, which is still mutable (you can't add or remove elements but you can replace existing elements).

Comment: Thanks Eran.. I didn't know that :) +1

Comment: @Eran Thanks for the elegant explanation. Understood it.